# React-native ошибка в методе map

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-native

Есть компонент который при загрузке скачивает json объект с сайта randomuser.me

[image]

Ошибка происходит при рендере компонента из-за того что он якобы совсем не объект, сама ошибка выглядит так

```
undefined is not an object (evalueting "users.map")
```

далее метод рендера

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сам объект выглядит вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я понимаю что после метода setState метод рендера должен вызываться автоматически, делал alert для проверки состояния, и мне выводилось

`[object Object]`

но я совсем не понимаю почему после очередного вызова рендера он не работает,
огромное спасибо за ответ, с новым годом!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В строке `const { users } = this.state.users` вы в объекте this.state.users пытаетесь найти данные под ключом users, то есть работаете с некоторой подобной структурой:

```
{ this: { state: { users: { users: [...] } } } }
```

хотя, судя по методу componentDidMount, вам надо обращаться по ключу results и работать уже с ним:

```
const { results } = this.state.users
```

Я бы порекомендовал вам еще раз почитать про деструктуризацию объектов, ну и про дебаггинг приложения (простейший способ - console.log, но это плохая практика, лучше сразу осваивать debugger и breakpoint)